# Best way to handle Controller bound Role parsing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, roles

I have a pattern I use to change the `ViewResult` of common controllers based on the users role. I reuse this code often, because occasionally I need to add `ViewBag` items to handle special cases.

It bothers me that I have to copy and paste code, but I can't think of an effective way to create a class or method outside of the controller that doesn't require a substantial amount of acrobatics (passing controllers and viewbags in signatures, etc) to function properly.

Is there a right way to do this?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string email = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
        Profile profile = 
            await Helper.GetProfile(HttpContext, User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
        if (profile == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile", new { exists = false });
        }
        else
        {
            switch (profile.Role)
            {
                case Role.VendorRepresentative:
                    ViewBag.Invoices = await Invoices.Instance.GetInvoicesByVendorRepIdAsync(profile.id);
                    return View("~/Views/Home/VendorRep.cshtml", profile);
                case Role.VendorCustomerService:
                    return View("~/Views/Home/VendorService.cshtml", profile);
                case Role.VendorSalesManager:
                    ViewBag.Invoices = new List<Invoice>();
                    return View("~/Views/Home/VendorManager.cshtml", profile);
                case Role.Distributor:
                    ViewBag.Invoices = new List<Invoice>();
                    return View("~/Views/Home/Distributor.cshtml", profile);
                default:
                    return View();
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `[Authorize]` attribute? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: ^^ thats just going to show them an Access Denied page if they are not in the role. It looks like he wants to dynamically change the view based on their role

Comment: Probably you want to write a custom *Filter*, which will redirect to them to the correct action based on their role

Comment: First thing is to keep the code S-O-L-I-D. Since every scenario is doing the same thing I would replace the conditional statements with polymorphism. That would be a good start in refactoring the code and would really flush out any design pattern you could use so you don't have to copy and paste. The filter Attribute could work well as mentioned above but I would clean up the conditional statements first.

Comment: @Train How would you recommend implementing polymorphism? An extension method, static helper that returns a ViewResult, or other means?

Comment: I would start with interfaces and objects. `IHomeView` with methods like '.GetView() and GetViewBag' and clases like `homeVendorView: IHomeView` I would also refactor to have the `httpContext` and the `Helper` injected in those class constructors with some IOC container so that you don't have to pass them around for every class. I can try to whip something up if I get some more time.

Comment: For me I keep it simple. I add an action method for each role. It's more additive code but it really helps out when the logic gets more complex.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when you centralize a process. It must contain logic identifying each consumer group, and it must contain each's processing.

The fact that you reuse the same model and then attach those consumer-specific "extras" to the ViewBag only proves that the model is not representative of the process. When a process only has very minor changes for each consumer group, the model is like a product family. Each group is represented by a variant. These scenarios will encourage you to design a base model. For example, you would associate the Role enumerations with their respective Index Views and perhaps Actions which modify. To truly represent a product family, your model should allocate room for the ViewBag items you're dumping out there.

However, standardizing (centralizing) a core product for variants does not prevent requirements from conflicting. Managers will want to impersonate users or have user page accesses timestamped. One group will want UI elements to data others cannot have access to. The product-family model works up until a certain point, until each group's requests contain enough processing to need separating due to centralization complexity.

http://www.powersemantics.com/p.html

Instead of processing via interpretation, which requires reading the entire code body to ascertain what processing happens for each group, approach the problem by translating the request into a process.

Think of every step in the process as being represented by the consumer's Index request. They're not just explicitly specified by the web page call to Index, but that can change. Each role's Index request is actually a composite instruction for the steps it represents. Therefore, emit the process based on the request variables (Role), and finally invoke the sequence.

```
VendorRepresentative
* Authenticate
* Load invoices
Index for VendorRepresentative role translates to -> Auth + LoadInvoices

VendorSalesManager
* Authenticate
* Instantiate invoices
Index for VendorSalesManager role translates to -> Auth + InstantiateInvoices
```

Now your process can easily grow if another group needs to be added. Also, if your users need control to run a step (or not, or specify values to it), this model allows you to map their arguments directly to process instruction.